# Toad SQL Query: Sorting by a column, then removing duplicates of that column based on the max of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

Currently, I have a script that produces the following output:

```
Employee/Password_Created_Date
1                 Date Newest
1                 Date Older
1                 Date Oldest
2                 Date Newest
2                 Date Older
2                 Date Oldest
3                 Date Newest
3                 Date Older
3                 Date Oldest
```

I want to produce results, with this query, where the employee column contains only unique results, and determine which duplicate remains based on the NEWEST password_created_date.

How can I accomplish this, in general?

Comment: There is no such thing as "TOAD SQL". Which DBMS are you using? Oracle?

Comment: Oracle. Yes I'm a complete nubile, I know.

Comment: You might want to look that word up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use Max(date) function and group by Employee to create a temp table or CTE and then link back to your original table with your temp/cte table.